# Multiple Updatepanel how child control get updated

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I have two update panels as

Updatepanel - 1

```
<div>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="up1" runat="server" RenderMode="Inline" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server" CssClass="snumtbx" MaxLength="0" TabIndex="0" OnTextChanged="txt1_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

Updatepanel - 2

```
<div>
   <asp:UpdatePanel ID="up2" runat="server" RenderMode="Inline" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt2" runat="server" CssClass="snumtbx" MaxLength="0" TabIndex="0" OnTextChanged="txt2_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

And code behind as

```
    protected void txt1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        txt1.Text  += "0";
    }

    protected void txt2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txt2.Text = txt2.Text += txt1.Text;
    }
```

Having two text boxes txt1 and txt2 with autopost back option, with initial values as 0

First i change the txt1 to 2 then txt1 get updated as 20

Then i change txt2 to 3 then txt2 will get updated as 320

First asynchronous update will change the txt1 value to 20,

And the second asynchronous update pick up this value "20" and updates the txt2 to "320"

My question how does update panel "up2" knows the value of txt1 which is in "up1".

Is  the asynchronous request send all the viewstate values, ie of both txt1 and txt2 ?

Can anyone elaborate on how ajax response update the page viewstate.
.

Comment: I am seeing only one update panel in code, where is second ?

Comment: sorry type error pls check now